# React Native NavigationStack screen component type mismatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build an app with React Native and React Navigation. I use typescript. I created RootStackParams type for my routes. The code is below:
App.tsx

```js
export type RootStackParams = {
  Explore: undefined;
  Restaurants: undefined;
  Profile: undefined;
  Restaurant: {
    name: string;
  };
};

const RootStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Profile">
        <RootStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Explore" component={ExploreScreen} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Restaurants" component={RestaurantsScreen} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Restaurant" component={RestaurantScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Restaurants.tsx

```js
type RestaurantsScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<
  RootStackParams,
  'Restaurants'
>;

const RestaurantsScreen: React.FC<RestaurantsScreenProps> = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Restaurants</Text>
      <ScrollView>
        {names.map((name, i) => (
          <RestaurantCard
            key={i}
            name={name}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Restaurant', {name: name})}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

The error I'm getting about type mismatch

```
Type '({ navigation, route }: RestaurantProps) => React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<ParamListBase, "Restaurant"> | undefined'.
  Type '({ navigation, route }: RestaurantProps) => React.JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'RestaurantProps': navigation, routets(2322)
```

I don't understand what I need to change to solve this issue

Comment: Can you take a look what is the type of the props object? I've tried this code locally and it seems to be working fine. Are your imports correct?

Answer (score 1):

Change from :

```
type RestaurantsScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<
  RootStackParams,
  'Restaurants'
>;

const RestaurantsScreen: React.FC<RestaurantsScreenProps> = ({navigation}) => {
  //
}
```

to:

```
type RestaurantsScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<
  RootStackParams,
  'Restaurants'
>;

const RestaurantsScreen = ({navigation}: RestaurantsScreenProps) => {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```js
const RestaurantsScreen: React.FC<RestaurantsScreenProps>
```

by the following

```js
const RestaurantsScreen: React.FunctionComponent<
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParams, "Restaurants">
>
```

I think this may solve the problem since the FC is currently unknown and by adding this line, it follows the names in your list.

Comment: it doesn't change anything, I'm still getting the same error, also I forgot to write it before, I'm getting it only in screens where I get props which are "Restaurants" and "Restaurant"

Comment: Could you show your code from the working component and Restaurant component